# Slide in mobile menu from off screen - overflow issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

Given the following simple demo, I'm struggling to achieve the desired behaviour where I have a menu which is positioned off screen using translateX.

There are a couple of issues - firstly, if I set `overflow: hidden` on the body, it prevents the menu from being displayed, instead just showing whitespace when the menu is toggled open.

If I remove `overflow: hidden`, I then have the issue where the user can scroll beyond the width of the body due to the translateX behaviour (see for example if you toggle open the menu, then swipe/move the body back into position without using the menu toggle).

I'd also like the menu to be scrollable when open, but that the partially hidden rest of the page content be fixed in position. I've set `position: fixed` on the container when the menu is toggled open but it has no effect.

Grateful for any help as I'm going round in circles with this one!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.mobile-menu-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('body').toggleClass('mobile-menu-open');
  });

  // Close mobile menu if user clicks anywhere outside of the visible menu
  $(document).on('click touchstart', function(e) {

    if (!$(e.target).closest('.mobile-menu-toggle').length &&
      !$(e.target).closest('.main-menu-mobile').length) {


      if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-menu-open')) {
        $('body').removeClass('mobile-menu-open');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

body.mobile-menu-open {
  transform: translateX(80%);
}

body.mobile-menu-open .container {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header:before,
.header:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
  /*transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;*/
  /*transition: none;*/
  background: red;
}

.main-menu-mobile {
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="header">
  <div class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="#" class="mobile-menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="main-menu-mobile">
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/girls">Girls</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/boys">Boys</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/footwear">Footwear</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/equipment">Equipment</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/activities">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/clearance">Clearance</a>
              </li>
              <li class="view-all"><a href="/women/jackets">View All Jackets &gt;&gt;</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/jackets">Jackets</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/girls">Girls</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/boys">Boys</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/footwear">Footwear</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/equipment">Equipment</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/activities">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/clearance">Clearance</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/jackets">Jackets</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/girls">Girls</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/boys">Boys</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/footwear">Footwear</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/equipment">Equipment</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/activities">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/clearance">Clearance</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/jackets">Jackets</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/girls">Girls</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/boys">Boys</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/footwear">Footwear</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/equipment">Equipment</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/activities">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/clearance">Clearance</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-subcategory">
            <h4><a href="/jackets">Jackets</a></h4>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/girls">Girls</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/boys">Boys</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/footwear">Footwear</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/equipment">Equipment</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/activities">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/clearance">Clearance</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="container">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec dui.
    Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at lorem
    non hendrerit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dunno if this helps, but here's a different approach to the menu https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmdBBE

Comment: Cheers @MichaelCoker, though I need to push the container to the right (unfortunately)

Comment: I need to run in a few seconds, but I whipped this up. Again, not sure if it helps, but it's fun to tinker with :) https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRMWwg

Answer (score 0):

So one approach is you can wrap the elements you're trying to manipulate in a container (you'll see this a lot in older websites, with a top level  called "wrapper"). I updated your snippet with this in mind and cleaned up the CSS to make it work.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div>blah</div>
  <div>blah</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/646tueyL/

I remember this approach causing issues when you have to handle responsiveness, there might be a more advanced way using JS or rethinking your markup structure.